# Error MSB8036: The windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 was not found

Tags: c++, sdk, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

OS: Windows 10 64bit
Platform: Visual Studio 2019

I'm compiling C++ DLL project.
Although I installed "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763)" and "Visual Studio SDK", the visual studio can"t see the SDK.
I try to "Retarget Solution" but there is no list of Windows SDKs.
The WindowsSdkDir, WindowsSdkDir_10 environment variables are empty.

How do I get the Visual Studio 2019 to detect the installation of the Windows SDK and associate it to my project

Comment: There is an SDK selection in the project settings.

Comment: set WindowsTargetPlatformVersion to 10.0 in csproj which uses highest installed SDK version.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can select a specific Windows SDK (exact version) or "newest" SDK in your project properties (right click, properties).

I think your project uses some specific Windows SDK Version which is not installed on your machine. To make your project Windows SDK-version independent you should go to the properties page and select "Windows 10 SDK (newest)" - or similar